# Simplify mapping multiple children elements in CasperJS to use only one function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have this code, which works, but would like to simplify it. In particular, I believe there is a shorthand method for referring to children elements so that I do not need to write multiple functions. Please let me know if there is a shorthand method to simplify this code!

The current code is

```
function getLineNumbers() {
var lineNumber = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(1)');
return Array.prototype.map.call(lineNumber, function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent;
});  }

function getSKUs() {
var SKU = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(2)');
return Array.prototype.map.call(SKU, function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent;
}); }

function getDescriptions() {
var description = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(3)');
return Array.prototype.map.call(description, function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent;
}); }

function getPrices() {
var price = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(4)');
return Array.prototype.map.call(price, function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent;
}); }

function getQuantities() {
var quantity = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(5)');
return Array.prototype.map.call(quantity, function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent;
}); }

function getTotals() {
var total = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(6)');
return Array.prototype.map.call(total, function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent;
});  }
```

Which I then call with the following code in a later function:

```
lineNumber = lineNumber.concat(this.evaluate(getLineNumbers));
SKU = SKU.concat(this.evaluate(getSKUs));
description = description.concat(this.evaluate(getDescriptions));
price = price.concat(this.evaluate(getPrices));
quantity = quantity.concat(this.evaluate(getQuantities));
total = total.concat(this.evaluate(getTotals));
```

Is there any way to simplify this code so I only need one function (e.g., getInvoiceData) that appropriately links the child element to the correct array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use a function (CSS selector `:nth-child()`) to select a specific child element. You can have only one function and pass the intended child index into the page context through a separate argument:

```
function getText(i) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child('+i+')');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(elem) {
    return elem.textContent;
  });
}
lineNumber = lineNumber.concat(this.evaluate(getText, 1));
SKU = SKU.concat(this.evaluate(getText, 2));
...
```